# ASP.NET wrong model type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a website and I'm struggling with the Models I pass to my Views. I ended up testing if it worked in the most basic way to be sure I hadn't done something obviously wrong. Still doesn't work :

My Controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        List<Model_Test> model = new List<Model_Test>
                {
                new Model_Test{Name = "Henri", Age = 24, City = "Paris"},
                new Model_Test{Name = "Jacob", Age = 18, City = "Caen"},
                new Model_Test{Name = "Patrick", Age = 57, City = "Lille"},
                new Model_Test{Name = "Youri", Age = 13, City = "Bordeaux"},
                };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

My Model :

```
public class Model_Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And my View is the view I created by right-clicking the ActionResult Test(). I set it to List with Model-test as a Model.

`@model IEnumerable<AVdevWebsite.Models.Model_Test>`

Yet I can't display my small List since I get this error :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type "System.Collections.Generic.List"1[AVdevWebsite.Models.Model_Test]", but this dictionary requires a model item of type "AVdevWebsite.Models.Model_User".

Thank you !

**Edit :**

Main View :

```
<!-- #region Modal -->
                        using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {
                            @model AVdevWebsite.Models.Model_User

                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                            <div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                                 aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <div class="form-signin">
                                                <img class="mb-4" src="~/Content/Images/User_Icon.png" width="72" height="72" />
                                                <h2 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Se Connecter</h2>
                                                <hr />
                                                @if (Session[ErrorAlerts.ERRORALERT] != null)
                                                {
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">@Session[ErrorAlerts.ERRORALERT]</div>
                                                }

                                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "sr-only" })
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Identifiant" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "sr-only" })
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Mot de Passe" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                                <hr />

                                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
                                                <a class="disabled btn btn-lg btn-primary">Invité</a>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        <!-- #endregion -->
```

And here is the partial View :

```
@model IEnumerable<AVdevWebsite.Models.Model_Test>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test_ManageUsers";
}

<h2>Test_ManageUsers</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    ...
</table>
```

The error was due to the Main View asking for a @model.

Comment: Based on the code provided, this looks correct.  You don't have a duplicate "@model" statement at the top of the view or something weird?  Are you positive that it's using the correct view?  Try explicitly specifying the view View("Test", model), assuming that the view is correctly named "Test.cshtml" in the Views folder.

Comment: You Controller is working with `Model_Test` and the View expect a `Model_User`. So as @BryanLewis suggest check if you a "loading" the correct view.

Comment: Also check your view to see if there are any other views being rendered within it.  It's possible your Controller and View model associations are in sync, but your primary view may be passing its model into another view that's expecting a model of a different type.   (e.g. does your view display user information by means of a partial view that's expecting a Model_User typed model?)

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick reaction. You're right @Steven, my main Layout used a model Model_User for a modal form, I just need to focus on its scope right?

Comment: Add the code for your partial view as well as the line from your main view where you are including it.

Comment: @BryanLewis I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a little trouble understanding how all these particular pieces fit together, so I'll try to offer some general MVC tips.

MVC works on the premise of the View dictating the layout/presentation specifics of the requested information, the Model represents the data requested, and the Controller does the work of constructing the Model and providing it to the View to generate the response.

Structurally, Views can be treated as components, and the "final" view can be created from multiple view components.  Views are generally coded against specific Model types, though, so nesting view components together can become kind of complicated pretty quickly.

There are a couple of ways that I know of to handle this situation as I understand it.

**1)** through complex Model objects.  You can define the Model to be whatever you need it to be, and you need to make sure your Model has all the "stuff" your View needs.  If the view has partial views nested within it, then a complex primary model can be designed to hold all the model information needed by the sub-views components.

In that case, your models might look something like this (**NOTE: Model_Test has a Model_User property named User**):

```
public class Model_User
{
    // Properties go here...
}

public class Model_Test
{
    public Model_User User { get; set; }

    // Properties go here...
}
```

your User view might look this this:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Model_User

@*View stuff goes here*@
```

and your Test view might look like this:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Model_Test

<h2>Test</h2>

@Html.Partial("User", Model.User)
```

In order to support that, your controller would need to create the User_Model as part of the process of creating the Test_Model:

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        // Build user model here
        var userModel = new Model_User();

        // Build test model so that it contains the user model
        var model = new Model_Test();
        model.User = userModel;

        return View(model);
    }
```

**2)** Alternatively you can delegate responsibility of handling the model-building to the Controller by way of a separate action method.  That way, the primary model doesn't necessarily have to have all the sub-view "stuff" contained within it, it can call out to the appropriate controller action and let it handle that.

In this case, your primary model is less complex; it can be stream-lined more in line with the view(s) it directly supports, but the draw back can be hidden complexity and repetition of server operations.

For this approach, your code might look something like the following:

For this, the models can be kept more simple (NOTE: Model_Test doesn't have to know anything about Model_User in this case)

```
public class Model_User
{
    // Properties go here...
}

public class Model_Test
{
    // Properties go here...
}
```

The controller would have a new action that generates the partial view for User (and handles building the supporting model)

```
public ActionResult User()
{
    // Build user model here
    var model = new Model_User();
    return PartialView(model);
}

public ActionResult Test()
{
    // Build test model here.  Model doesn't have to "know" anything about user details
    var model = new Model_Test();
    return View(model);
}
```

The Test view relies on the Controller to do that work by way of that Action:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Model_Test


<h2>Test</h2>

@Html.Action("User")
```